# Apache Spark Word2Vec throws org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: requirement failed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I run spark word2vec on a 2G of data with the following config using pyspark 3.0.0.

```py
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("word2vec") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "32g") \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

And with running code simply like following,

```py
sentence = sample_corpus.withColumn('sentences',f.split(sample_corpus.sentences, ',')).select('sentences')
word2vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=300, inputCol="sentences", outputCol="result", minCount=10)
model = word2vec.fit(sentence)
```

However, it will throw following error during the computation which does not give many useful information for debugging.

```
FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(driver, fedora, 34105, None), shuffleId=2, mapIndex=0, mapId=73, reduceId=0, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: requirement failed
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:748)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:663)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$SuccessFetchResult.(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:981)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchLocalBlocks(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.initialize(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:536)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:83)
    ... 14 more

)
```

My machine has 64g memory. I wonder what is the cause here and how can I fix it. Thank you.

Comment: What JDK version are you running with?

Comment: FYI https://towardsdatascience.com/fetch-failed-exception-in-apache-spark-decrypting-the-most-common-causes-b8dff21075c

Comment: @mazaneicha Java 11

Comment: @zhang-yuan I am not sure how your article solve my situation as my situation does not have the same exception output as the article has stated.